# javascript substring

Tags: javascript, string, substring

the most darndest thing! the following code prints out 'llo' instead of the expected 'wo'. i get such surprising results for a few other numbers. what am i missing here?

```
alert('helloworld'.substring(5, 2));
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You're confusing [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Substring) and [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substr): `substring()` expects two indices and not offset and length. In your case, the indices are 5 and 2, ie characters 2..4 will be returned as the higher index is excluded.

Comment: The second answer is better; it has examples

Answer (score 60):

You have three options in Javascript:

```
//slice
//syntax: string.slice(start [, stop])
"Good news, everyone!".slice(5,9); // extracts 'news'

//substring 
//syntax: string.substring(start [, stop])
"Good news, everyone!".substring(5,9); // extracts 'news'

//substr
//syntax: string.substr(start [, length])
"Good news, everyone!".substr(5,4); // extracts 'news'
```

Answer (score 17):

Check the `substring` [**syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp):

> **substring(from, to)**
>
> **from**      Required. The index where to
>   start the extraction. First character
>   is at index 0
>
> **to**    Optional. The index
>   **where to stop the extraction**. If
>   omitted, it extracts the rest of the
>   string

I'll grant you it's a bit odd. Didn't know that myself.

What you want to do is

```
alert('helloworld'.substring(5, 7));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert('helloworld'.substring(5, 2));
```

The code above is wrong because the first value is the start point to the end point.E.g move from char 5 which is `o` and go to char 2 which is the `l` so will get `llo` So you have told it to go backwards.

What yuou want is

```
alert('helloworld'.substring(5, 7));
```

Answer (score 2):

See syntax below:

```
str.substring(indexA, [indexB])
```

If `indexA > indexB`, the `substring()` function acts as if arguments were reversed.

Consider documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done...

```
var stringValue = 'Welcome to India';

// if you want take get 'India' 
// stringValue.substring(startIndex, EndIndex)
   stringValue.substring(11, 16); // O/p 'India'
```