# JS how to do "substr"?

Tags: javascript, substr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989009/javascript-substring)

How can I do substr (php) in JS?

Example code from PHP:

```
<?php
$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef"
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
?>
```

Comment: Google still seems to work: http://www.google.ie/search?q=javascript+substring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very similar to PHP:

```
var rest = "abcdef".substr(start, length);
```

You also can read more about this function here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: Actually `substr` in both PHP and Javascript uses `length`, not `end`

Answer (score 2):

The following will reproduce it.

```
"abcdef".substr(-1);
"abcdef".substr(-2);
"abcdef".substr(-3, 1);
```

Comment: I don't think IE supports negative starting positions with `.substr()`, though it does with `.slice()`...