# Cut substring after last slash?

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

How can i remove sub string (after last slash) from string in javascript like

c:/Program File/Internet Explorer

to

c:/Program File/

Comment: You need to do some research before you ask questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989009/javascript-substring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try the below negated char class based regex.

```
string.replace(/[^\/]*$/, "")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/6)

- `[^\/]*` matches any char but not forward slash zero or more times.
- `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

Answer (score 6):

Try lastIndexOf()

```js
var str = "c:/Program File/Internet Explorer";
var newStr = str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = newStr;
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.regexr.com if you want to test regular expressions. Something like .*/ would match everything up to the slash character.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "c:/Program File/Internet Explorer";
var output = str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need lastIndexOf and substr

```
var t = "c:/Program File/Internet Explorer";
t = t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf("/"));
alert(t);
```

or you can use the following.

```
    var removeLastPart = function(url) 
{
        var lastSlashIndex = url.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (lastSlashIndex > url.indexOf("/") + 1)
{
            return url.substr(0, lastSlashIndex);
        } 
else 
{
            return url;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filePath = "c:/Program File/Internet Explorer";
var displayUptoSpecifiedChar = filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
console.log(filePath.slice(0, displayUptoSpecifiedChar));
```

Comment: See the output in browser console