# Delete special characters from string with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some string like this:

`http://my-site.com/name-274x183.jpg`

And I want to cut it down to something like this (Delete -274x183) :

`http://my-site.com/name.jpg`

How can I do this with javascript or jQuery?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989009/javascript-substring)

Comment: Broad bcuz the URL needs to be parsed.

Comment: @freedomn-m just String#substring won't do that safely.

Comment: @Someone the question is too vague, it's possible that they just want to remove those specific characters, or they may need a more generic features - there's no way to know given they've used the term "special characters" and there aren't any "special" characters in the example and they've requested jquery for basic string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do that. Use regular expressions instead:

```js
const url = 'http://my-site.com/name-274x183.jpg'
const result = url.replace(/\/([^/]+)-\d+x\d+\.(\w+)$/, '/$1.$2')

console.log(result)
```